# javascript - url regexp not proper

Tags: javascript, regex

I am tryint to validate URL with js.

```
function validateURL(url) {
  var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.|https:\/\/|http:\/\/){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
  return urlregex.test(url);
}
```

but but i want that `google.com` will also pass, but it is not passing thru this regexp.

what is wrong with regexp?

I want these urls to pass thru regexp:

```
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
https://www.google.com
https://google.com
google.com
www.google.com
```

Comment: `localhost` is an URL as well?

Comment: Very simple example: `^((http(s)?|ftp)://)?([\w\d]+\.?)+` via [RegexPal](http://tinyurl.com/otwq99y)

Comment: @doniyor What about `customer.dev.site.com`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, honestly, i dont know how deeply corect it should be. i think, for this, i need to curl the url and say if it is valid or not..

Comment: @doniyor Are you trying to find out if an address can be looked up with DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function validateURL(url) {
  var urlregex = new RegExp("^((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[0-9A-Za-z]+\.[0-9A-Za-z]+)$");
  return urlregex.test(url);
}
```

´
**DEMO**
http://regex101.com/r/rG8wP9

***OR:***

```
function validateURL(url) {
if (/^((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[0-9A-Za-z]+\.[0-9A-Za-z]+)$/im.test(url)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

***EXPLANATION:***

```
^ assert position at start of a line
1st Capturing group ((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[0-9A-Za-z]+\.[0-9A-Za-z]+)
(?:https?:\/\/)? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
http matches the characters http literally (case sensitive)
s? matches the character s literally (case sensitive)
Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
: matches the character : literally
\/ matches the character / literally
\/ matches the character / literally
(?:www\.)? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
www matches the characters www literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally
[0-9A-Za-z]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally
[0-9A-Za-z]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of a line
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: Upvoting your nice explanation Tuga. :)

Answer (score 0):

> what is wrong with regexp?

This part of regexp:

```
([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)
```

can't be matched with "google.com" in your example. But it matches with wrong domain addresses like **google.** Something like this:

```
(?:[0-9A-Za-z]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}
```

is more correct and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Several things not working in this regexp. For instance nothing happen after the period at the end. Also never need `{1}` as every expression matched once by default. Main problem is the `|` because the branches are not inside `()` so after each `|` the match restart completely

This is your regexp cleaned up. For instance pulling things into groups, see the `|` inside `()`.

`isMatch =  (/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[0-9a-z]+\.[a-z]+/im.test(url))`